Latex Error in the Rmarkdown complitation
I have been using the Rmardown for producing pdf documents and everything was running fime but then suddenly the following error started appearing when I knit the file. I am using TinyTex for LaTex
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: l3kernel
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: l3kernel-dev
! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)        
(LaTeX)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX)        is dated 2024-05-08, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX)        at least 2024-05-27.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile First_draft.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See First_draft.log for more info.
Execution halted

The following is the YAML of my file. But I don't think the problem is there because all my files are not giving the same error since morning.
---
title: "Are co for Pn"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
  - \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
  - \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
author:
  - name: Ali            
    email: al@sk        
    affiliation: Rkistan        
    correspondingauthor: true
address:
  - code: Reseatment   
    organization: nk of Pakis
    addressline: Iar Road
    city: Karachi   
    state: Sindh
    postcode: 74000
    country: Pakistan
# footnote:
#   - code: 1
#     text: "This is the first author footnote."
abstract: |
  In this paper we have used 
keywords: 
  - Consumers
  - Inflation
  - Inflation Expectations
journal: "La economics"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
classoption: preprint, 3p, authoryear
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: apalike
linenumbers: false
numbersections: true
# Use a CSL with `citation_package = "default"`
# csl: https://www.zotero.org/styles/elsevier-harvard
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
---

Following is the R details:
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$crt
[1] "ucrt"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "3.1"

$year
[1] "2023"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "16"

$`svn rev`
[1] "84548"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)"

$nickname
[1] "Beagle Scouts"

PS: I am a not an expert on the subject and have learnt everything on the internet but I'm stuck on this one as all my projects are not working now and its stressing me out.
If you need any further information please reply in the comment
